# Split more complicated String to get the numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have a given String that represents the age in format:
**"YY yr MM mo"** or
**"Y yr MM mo"** or
**"YY yr M mo"** or
**"Y yr M mo"**
where YY/Y represent years (example: 5 or 44) and MM/M represent months (example: 2 or 11). Just to be clear, I give example of a String pAge = "11 yr 5 mo" or String pAge = "4 yr 10 mo".

Now I'd like to split this String and print it only as a numbers in a two separate text fields that represents years and months in age.
To get years I writing a function:

```
    String arr[] = pAge.split(" ", 2);
    return arr[0];
```

And another function to get months:

```
    int i = pAge.indexOf("yr", pAge.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    int k = pAge.indexOf(" ", pAge.indexOf(" ") + 4);
    String s = pAge.substring(i, k);
    return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

So, first method looks nice and it's easy but is there is any simpler way to write the second function? Both are working well and giving a correct output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Why doesn't the third result from the split give you what you want?

Comment: So your actual question is how to split them ***without*** using `String.split()` method? I don't understand why don't you just use .split().

Comment: No, my question is how to split them using something that will be not so intricately as my second method. Your answer is correct. I didn't know how to use .split(). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the 4 cases given by you are the ***same***. All of them have 4 parts delimited by a space.

This means that you can use `.split()` for all 4 cases:

```
String[] tokens = pAge.split(" ");
int years = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);  //get first token
int months = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);  //get third token
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this untested pseudo code:

```
String tokens[] = pAge.split(" ");

if (tokens.length != 4 || tokens[1] != "yr" || tokens[3] != "mo")
   throw new SyntaxError("pAge is not 'N yr N mo'");

String years = tokens[0];
String month = tokens[2];
```